# pstree does not show every process

Tags: process, ps

I opened a terminal made `sudo su` run the nano editor in the background by running it as `nano&`.

I tried to find the newly started nano process in the process list.
To do that, I typed

```
ps aux|grep -i nano
```

-> Saw the newly created nano

but when I tried to see the same nano process with pstree, it did not list the nano. I used

```
pstree -p|grep -i nano
```

No output was shown.

Comment: `pstree -ap | grep -i nano` ... with `-a` should show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pstree`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/pstree.1.html) through a pipe .. Check it with:

```
pstree -p | tee
```

might not show the full command/command-line arguments depending on how far to the right side of the tree a process is ... It might show a partial command followed by a plus sign indicating the output is shortened like `--nan+` instead of `--nano` or might not even show that if that process is far enough to the right side of the processes tree.

Therefore, if you need to show command line arguments, then use the option for that which is `-a`:

```
pstree -ap | grep -i nano
```

Although `grep` is more suitable to `ps` than it is to `pstree` as the "*tree*" part will be lost ... If you have to use `pstree` with `grep` then at least use `grep`'s `-B` and `-A` options to show a few lines before and after the match so that the "*tree*" is at least partially shown like so:

```
pstree -ap | grep -B 5 -A 5 -i nano
```

Comment: `-B 5 -A 5` can be replaced with `-C 5`.

Comment: @Unmitigated Thanks for your comment ... That is correct as well as alternatively using only a dash `-` and a number i.e. `-5` at least on Ubuntu's implementation of GNU grep, but `-B` and `-A` offer more control of course.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that `pstree` truncates long lines when piped e.g.

```
# pstree -sp "$$"
systemd(1)───sddm(1007)───sddm-helper(1097)───lxqt-session(1114)───qterminal(1475)───bash(1478)───sudo(28929)───sudo(28930)───su(28931)───bash(28932)─┬─nano(28938)                          
                                                                                                                                                      └─pstree(29086)
```

but

```
# pstree -sp "$$" | cat                                                                                                                   
systemd(1)---sddm(1007)---sddm-helper(1097)---lxqt-session(1114)---qterminal(1475)---bash(1478)---sudo(28929)---sudo(28930)---su(28+
```

(notice everything after `sudo(28930)---su(28+` is omitted).

You can pass the `-l` or `--long` option to prevent that, i.e.

```
# pstree -lsp "$$" | grep -i nano                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                      |-nano(28938)
```

or avoid the issue by not starting all the way from PID 1 - for example, starting from the parent shell's PID:

```
# pstree -p "$$" | grep -i nano
            |-nano(28938)
```

or (perhaps better) avoid grepping the pstree output (which is really intended for human eyes) by using `pgrep` instead:

```
# pgrep -af nano
28938 nano
```

Comment: What a coincidence :) +1

Comment: @Raffa indeed ;-p

Comment: Thank both of you. Since Rafta is the first I chose his answer. But thank you steeldriver for your super explanation

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of `pgrep`